# jQuery keyup code doesn't work 20% of the time for users

Tags: jquery, html, forms, autocomplete

Context:

We currently have a contact form that have a requirement to be three fields. Full name, Email and Phone. The marketing team have it 100% set in stone that those three fields will be as is, no changing.

Issue:

In order to send through the data to the server properly. I have to split the **Full Name** field value to seperate **First Name** and **Last Name** values and write these into hidden inputs on keyup.

However, 10%-20% of the time, all of the field information is coming through as just the first name, leaving the surname blank.

I don't know how this is happening, my only thinking is that the users could be using autocomplete? But on my tests on different devices, this isn't the case.

How can I reliably sort the issue or even understand how this is happening?

Code:

```
<form class="enquiry-form" action="XXXXX" method="POST" id="enquiry-form">
    <label class="pt-2 w-100 text-left"> YOUR NAME:
       <div id="opt_type" class="amt-form-holder w-100 ">
           <input type="text" class="form-control amt-form w-100" id="full_name" name="full_name" placeholder="Name...">
       </div>
    </label>

    <input type=hidden name="first_name" id="first_name" value="">
    <input type=hidden name="last_name" id="last_name" value="">
</form>


<script>
  $('#full_name').on('keyup change input', function () {
    var last_name = $(this).val().split(" ").pop();
    var first_name = $(this).val();
    var lastIndex = first_name.lastIndexOf(" ");
    first_name = first_name.substring(0, lastIndex);
    $('#first_name').val(first_name);
    $('#last_name').val(last_name);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Would it not make more sense (and avoid the issue) to perform the name splitting when the form is submit?

Comment: What about just do it on blur? `$('#full_name').on('blur',`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I agree, I haven't been able to do so with the form action linking to an external system so catching the field on submit doesn't take into affect

Comment: *"I have to split the Full Name field value to seperate First Name and Last Name values and write these into hidden inputs on keyup."* **This will be wrong** for a **lot** of people. If you need separate "first name" and "last name" fields in the database, the marketing people will have to live with having two fields in the UI. **Only the user** knows how they prefer allocating their name between those two fields. The concepts of "first name" and "last name" are not universal, a lot of people have to shoehorn their proper name into these unnecessarily-limiting fields.

Comment: The form action shouldn't be relevant to the problem. Simply hook a `submit` event handler to the form and put your logic in there

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Yeah. That's part of what I meant by "allocating" but good to call it out explicitly.

Comment: What @T.J.Crowder says is true. Here in holland for example we have words that are part of the last name. For example "Jan de Boer" where "Jan" is de first name and "de Boer" the last name. My girlfriend who's Indonesian doesn't even have an official lastname but 3 firstnames (her last firstname she uses a lot as a lastname in forms)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I do completely understand this, in order to cater to users we should really have the appropriate fields. The purpose of the website is primarily lead-gen and then aftercare salesmen following the opportunity up will confirm this data at a later date

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Have just changed the logic to be on submit, do the splitting, then return true to submit the form. Works fine on my tests, will have to see if we see less of these issues in the coming days. Thanks a lot for the help Rory (and others!)